# NSURLConnection Asynchronous Request inside a for-loop does not properly download NSData (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I've written a class called Movie whose initializer takes an integer "id" to retrieve data from the Rotten Tomatoes API:

```
init(id: Int) {
    let movieURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/\(id).json?apikey=\(apiKey)")!

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: movieURL), queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (response, movieData, error) -> Void in
        var movieJson = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(movieData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]

        self.id = self.idFromMovieJson(movieJson)
        self.title = self.titleFromMovieJson(movieJson)
        // ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.delegate!.movieDidDownload(self)
        })
    }        
}
```

If I instantiate a Movie object with a correct id, everything goes as expected. This is what I've written in another class:

```
var movie = Movie(id: 771351912)
movie.delegate = self

func movieDidDownload(movie: Movie) {
    println(movie.title)
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Optional("Interstellar")
```

However, when I try to instantiate a Movie object inside a for-loop like this:

```
let ids = [771351912, 771380953, 771041011, 13863, 12490, 771311818, 771321699, 11691]
for id in ids {
    var movie = Movie(id: id)
    movie.delegate = self
}
```

The print results are not very encouraging:

```
Optional("Super 8") 
Optional("Interstellar") 
Optional("Pulp Fiction")
nil 
Optional("The Nightmare Before Christmas") 
nil
nil
Optional("Nightcrawler")
```

Worst of all, the println() output is different each time I build and run my code:

```
Optional("Interstellar")
Optional("Pulp Fiction")
Optional("Super 8")
Optional("Nightcrawler")
Optional("The Nightmare Before Christmas")
nil
nil
nil
```

I even tried to create different NSOperationQueues with different names to use in the NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest() method but that didn't work out too:

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()
queue.name = "\(id)"
```

I guess that the problem is related to the fact I'm sending too many requests at the same time. I've placed `sleep(1)` in the ids for-loop and it actually prints the movie titles properly.

Does anybody know how to asynchronously make multiple requests inside a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

The swift println() function is asynchronous, and the order of delivery isn't guaranteed, so you may get all kinds of confusing results if you use it like this.

I'd suggest switching to using NSLog() instead, as that will give more consistent results.

Also, creating a new throwaway NSOperationQueue() for each request seems like a bad idea, as the queue may get released before the operation executes. Try using NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() instead.

As an added benefit, using a single queue instead of a different queue for each request should ensure that the movies get downloaded in the order you've requested them.

Comment: I've just casually figured out the nature of the problem… **Rotten Tomatoes limits the queries per second :)** Thank you for the quick response Nick! Very appreciated.